# how to insert just the row I updated in one table into another table by using trigger in myspl?

Tags: mysql

I am learning to create a trigger that can insert the row I update in one table into another table.

the query below is my creating trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_edit_deliverycompany BEFORE UPDATE ON `deliverycompany`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO `editor_log` (`edit_table`, `edit_field`, `editor`, `edit_time`)
   SELECT 'deliverycompany',`deliverycompany`.`CompanyID`,USER(),CURDATE() FROM `deliverycompany` ;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

when the trigger is fired, All rows in 'deliverycompany' are insert into the 'editor_log' rather than just the row I updated.

How to just select the row I update
 if using where how can I locate the row I updated (any value in the row)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_edit_deliverycompany BEFORE UPDATE ON `deliverycompany`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO `editor_log` (`edit_table`, `edit_field`, `editor`, `edit_time`) VALUES (OLD.deliverycompany, OLD.deliverycompany, USER(),CURDATE()) ;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```